# How to iterate through Reverse ManytoOne sets, Attribute Error

Tags: django

```
key = modelobj.__class__.__name__
keyval = modelobj.pk
sets = ['cat_set', 'dog_set']
for x in set:
    test = eval(key).objects.get(pk=keyval).eval(x).values()
    print(test)
```

The entries in the 'sets' list have a ManytoOne relationship (already defined in the model file) with the 'key'. When I run this script I get the error: "AttributeError: 'Activities' object has no attribute 'eval'" for the "eval(x)" part (the first eval(key) works fine).
For instance, if I change the line to the following code, it runs fine but I need to be less explicit:

```
test = eval(key).objects.get(pk=keyval).cat_set.values()
```

Comment: You can't concatenate like this, just split your statement in two statements. And use `getattr` instead of `eval`. And your first `eval` is unnecessary if you just used `modelobj.__class__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getattr` and refer the model directly (why would you need to get the model name and run `eval`?):

```
model = modelobj.__class__
keyval = modelobj.pk
sets = ['cat_set', 'dog_set']

for x in set:
    test = getattr(model.objects.get(pk=keyval), x).values()
    print(test)
```